# check if a graph is singly connected

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I refer  the definition of singly connected graph from Introduction to algorithms CLRS 3rd edition ch.22 exercise 22.3-13 as `A directed graph G = (V,E) is singly connected if G contains at most one simple path from u to v for all vertices u, v belongs to V` . I noticed that the cycles in the graph does not necessarily means that the graph is  not singly connected as paths involving cycles are not considered as simple path. A simple cycle in the directed graph can be represented uniquely by set of corresponding edges. Lets consider a certain directed graph satisfying the following two properties:
(1) it is having only tree and back edges in its DFS forest and
(2) all the sets representing each simple cycle in the graph are disjoint (i.e. they are not sharing any edge).
Now my question is : Is it true that every directed graph satisfying above two conditions must be a singly connected graph? Or just condition 1 is sufficient for graph to be singly connected?I am unable to find any counterexample

Comment: @tobias_k , consider a graph given by  G = ( (0, 1, 2),  ( (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0) ) ) . can you point out any such two path in this cycle of three nodes ?

Comment: Didn't see the "directed" bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found an counterexample. Assume this directed graph G having 5 nodes (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and 6 edges (0,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,3), (3,4), (4,0). If we start DFS at any node from the set (3, 4), we will have only tree and back edges. Clearly it satisfies condition 1 but not 2 and it is not a singly connected graph as there are two simple paths from node 1 to 0 ( 1->2->3->4->0 and 1->2->0 ). Surprisingly if we start DFS from any other node (i.e. from 0, 1, 2) , its DFS forest will contain atleast one forward edge. It is observed that the sets of edges representing simple cycles in this graph are {(0,1), (1,2), (2,0)} and {(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,0)} which shares edges (0,1) and (1,2). DFS forests obtained by choosing initial node from any of the nodes within the edges common between both sets (i.e. from 0, 1, 2) results in atleast one forward edge, whereas by choosing initial node from any of the remaining nodes (i.e. from 3, 4) results in only tree and backward edges in their DFS forests. It proves that condition 1 is not sufficient for a directed graph to be singly connected.